# Nodejs NPM failed to install node-geocoder, because of dependecies

Tags: node.js, google-maps, npm, google-geocoder

I have a problem with my npm. I want to install node-geocoder module, but the installation is failed, because the following error:

Error: No compatible version found: commander@'^2.6.0'

There are 2 dependencies for this module commander v2.6.0 and q v1.1.2 and both modules are installed, however I cannot install the node-geocoder.
Anyone has an idea why it is not working?

Comment: What your node version?

Comment: Or update your node, or try `npm install node-geocoder@2.10.0`.

Comment: Thanks a lot man it is working like a charm. How do you know that this version will work properly?